# Homotopy domination of mapping cylinders with a special condition

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that there exist continuous maps $f:Y\longrightarrow Z$ and $g:Z\longrightarrow Y$ so that $g\circ f\simeq 1_Y$. Also, let $h :X\longrightarrow Y$ be a  continuous map which induces an isomorphism of
fundamental groups. We know that $M_{h}\simeq Y$ and $M_{f\circ h}\simeq Z$, where $M_{h}=\frac{X\times I \cup Y}{(x,1)\sim h (x)}$ is the mapping cylinder of $h$.

**Is $\pi_2 (M_{h},X)$ a direct summand of  $\pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)$?**

Comment: Have your tried to construct the map $G$ from the homotopy from $g\circ f$ to $\operatorname{id}_Y$, restricted to $X\times I$, and $g$ on $Z$?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do the following : factor your map $F\colon M_h\to M_{f\circ h}$ as the inclusion $i\colon M_h\hookrightarrow M_h\cup_Y M_f$ followed by a map $q\colon M_h\cup_Y M_f\to M_{f\circ h}$. Then, construct a retract $r\colon M_h\cup_Y M_f\to M_h$. It is then enough to prove that the map $M_h\cup_Y M_f\to M_{f\circ h}$ is a weak-equivalence.

Let us first construct the map $q\colon M_h\cup_Y M_f\to M_{f\circ h}$ and show that it is a weak-equivalence. Consider the pushout diagram defining $M_h\cup_Y M_f$, where $i_0(y)=(y,0)$.

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
Y@>i_0>>M_f\\
@VjVV@VV\widetilde{j}V\\
M_{h}@>i>>M_h\cup_Y M_f\\
\end{CD}$$

To define $q$, it is enough to define two maps $q_f\colon M_f\to M_{f\circ h}$ and $q_h\colon M_h\to M_{f\circ h}$ such that $q_f\circ i_0= q_h\circ j$.
Set $q_f$ as the composition $M_f\to Z\hookrightarrow M_{f\circ h}$ and define $q_h$ via $q_h(x,t)=(x,t), q_h(y)=f(y)$. This defines the desired map $q\colon M_h\cup_ Y M_f\to M_{f\circ h}$.

Now, $\widetilde{j}$ and $q_f$ are homotopy equivalences, and so $q$ must induce isomorphisms on all homotopy groups. Since $q_{|X}\colon X\hookrightarrow M_{f\circ h}$ is equal to the inclusion, we have that $q$ induces isomorphisms on all relative homotopy groups.

Now, we define $r\colon M_h\cup_Y M_f\to M_{h}$. As earlier, it is enough to define $r_f\colon M_f\to M_h$ and $r_h\colon M_h\to M_h$, such that $r_f\circ i_0=r_h\circ j$. Take $r_h=Id_{M_h}$ and define $r_f$ via : $r_f(y,t)= H(y,t)$, and $r_f(z)=g(z)$. This defines $r$ such that $r\circ i= Id_{M_h}$.

Putting everything together, we have that the composite $M_h\xrightarrow{i} M_h\cup_Y M_f\xrightarrow{r} M_h$ is equal to the identity, and $\pi_n(M_h\cup_Y M_f,X)\simeq \pi_n(M_{f\circ h},X)$. This should imply the result you want.

Comment: Excuse me. By the answer, we have $q\circ i_f =q_h$ and $q\circ \tilde{j}=q_f$, But why $\tilde{j}$ and $i_f$ are homotopy equivalence? Why does $q$  induce isomorphisms on all homotopy groups?

Comment: I think  the map $\tilde{j}$ is  homotopy equivalence not the map $i$. I don't understand your mean about the map $i_f$ in the context.

Comment: I am sorry, I changed my mind on notations in the middle of the process of writing this answer, and forgot one occurence of $i_f$. $i_f$ is supposed to be $q_f$.

Comment: We have $q_f=q\circ\widetilde{j}$.  $q_f$ is an homotopy equivalence since $M_f$ and $M_{f\circ h}$ are both homotopy equivalent to $Z$, and $\widetilde{j}$ is also an homotopy equivalence. Then, by the two out of three property (or equivalently, passing to homotopy groups) we see that $q$ must be a weak equivalence.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete answer. I learned lots of things from your proof. Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering if I could ask another question in connected to the discussion.

Comment: Let $Z$ be  a finite wedge of spheres  containing circles,  $X$ be a finite wedge of circles and $h:X\to Y$ a map which induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups (in the question). We know $\pi_1 (X)$ acts on $\pi_2 (M_{h},X)$ and $\pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)$. As you proved, $\pi_2 (M_{h},X)$ is a direct summand of $\pi_n (M_{f\circ h},X)$ so that the action of $\pi_1 (X)$ is preserved throuth it. Since $h_*$ is an isomorphism and $\pi_2 (X)=0$, $\pi_2  (M_{h},X)$ is  abelian and so is a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. But this is not true for $\pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)$.

Comment: I wanted to prove that $\pi_2 (M_h ,X)$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. So I tried to show: (1): $\pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module, and (2): $\pi_2 (M_{h},X)$ is a direct summand of $\pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module.

Comment: Unfortunately, $\pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)$ is not abelian and so we can't say $\pi_n (M_{f\circ h},X)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. The only thing I have, is a short sequence of groups $1\to \pi_2 (Z)\to \pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)\to \pi_1 (X)\to 1$ and that $\pi_1 (X)$ is free. Since $\pi_1 (X)$ is free,  $\pi_2 (M_{f\circ h},X)=\pi_2 (Z)\rtimes \pi_1 (X)$.

Comment: Clearly, $\pi_2 (Z)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. But I don't know how to   show that $\pi_2 (M_h ,X )$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module.

Comment: I think you should ask another question. I suspect that the truth (or not) of your statement only relies on the long exact sequences, and on the maps between them. And this is a different question. I would try to phrase in a purely algebraic way, and link to this question for motivations.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if you could inform me about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment with a commutative diagram rather than a full answer.

Let $H\colon Y\times I\to Y$ be a homotopy between $\operatorname{id}_Y$ and $g\circ f$.
I though defining $G$ using the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X\times I@>H\circ(h\times\operatorname{id}_I)>>Y\times I\\
@VVV@VVV\\
M_{f\circ h}@>>>Y\times I@>r>\sim>M_h\\
@AAA@AAA\\
Z@>g>>Y\rlap{\;,}
\end{CD}$$
where $r$ is a strong deformation retract from $Y\times I$ to $M_h$.
This definitely works if $h$ is a cofibration, and it seems that one can use $H$ to construct the homotopy between $G\circ F$ and $\operatorname{id}_{M_h}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think your mean is that $H\circ (h\times id_I )$ is a map from  $X\times I$ to $Y$ in the first row of the diagram. Excuse me, could you tell me  what is the map $M_{f\circ h}\longrightarrow Y$ in the second row in the diagram?

Comment: Actually, I also want to keep the variable $t\in I$, so the upper map actually is $(x,t)\mapsto(H(h(x),t),t)$. The middle line is the unique map that makes the diagram commute. If you like, write $M_{\operatorname{id}_Y}$ for $Y\times I$ in the middle entry.

Comment: Sebastian Goette I understood that you actually define a map $K :X\times I \sqcup Z \longrightarrow Y\times \{ 1\}$ by $K ((x,t))=([H(h(x),t)],1)$ and $K (z)=([g(z)],1)$ if we consider the elements of Y of the form $[y]$ in the mapping cylinder $M_h$. Since $K$ is constant on each fiber of the quotient map $X\times I\sqcup Z\longrightarrow M_{f\circ h}$, so there exists unique map $G_1 :M_{f\circ h}\longrightarrow Y\times \{ 1\}$. Now we define $G:M_{f\circ h}\longrightarrow M_{h}$ by $G([x,t])=[H(h(x),t)]$ and $G([z])=[g(z)]$.

Comment: But I don't know yet how I define a homotopy between $G\circ F$ and $id_{M_{h}}$:(